# rsync not finding local directory when sending through SSH on pipeline

Tags: ssh, bitbucket, rsync, bitbucket-pipelines

Using bitbucket pipelines to push to our remote from the build process that you get from the pipeline.

This is a snippet of the `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file

```
- pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.2.2
        variables:
          SSH_USER: $PRODUCTION_USER
          SERVER: $PRODUCTION_SERVER
          COMMAND: '''rsync -zrSlh -e "ssh -p 22007" --stats --max-delete=0 $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/ $PRODUCTION_USER@$PRODUCTION_SERVER:home/$PRODUCTION_USER'''
          PORT: '22007'
```

The connection itself works, and it does run the command correctly once it is remoted onto the server...

```
INFO: Executing the pipe...
INFO: Using default ssh key
INFO: Executing command on {HOST}
ssh -A -tt -i /root/.ssh/pipelines_id -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 22007 {USER}@{HOST} 'rsync -zrSlh -e "ssh -p 22007" --stats --max-delete=0 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/ {USER}@{HOST}:home/{USER}'
bash: rsync -zrSlh -e "ssh -p 22007" --stats --max-delete=0 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/ {USER}@{HOST}:home/{USER}: No such file or directory
Connection to {HOST} closed.
```

I've tried to run the same command locally from the directory on my machine

```
ssh -A -tt -i /root/.ssh/pipelines_id -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 22007 {USER}@{HOST} 'rsync -zrSlh -e "ssh -p 22007" --stats --max-delete=0 "$PWD" {USER}@{HOST}:/home/{USER}'
```

but it just duplicates the home directory on the remote.

It looks to me like it's looking for the source directory on the server and not looking at the docker container from bitbucket (or the files on my local machine with `pwd`).

If I try to run the command without the `''` then it fails because it's using port 22 by default. I've also tried offsetting the command into a bash script and using `MODE: 'Script'` which is an acceptable pattern for the [plugin](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/ssh-run/src/master/), but I can't use my environment variables in the `sh` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found another way around this instead of needing a plugin, instead I'm running an rsync as a script step

```
image: atlassian/default-image:latest

- rsync -rltDvzCh --max-delete=0 --stats --exclude-from=excludes -e 'ssh -e none -p 22007' $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/ $PRODUCTION_USER@$PRODUCTION_SERVER:/home/$PRODUCTION_USER
```

It seems the `-e none` is an important addition, as is loading in the atlassian image, as fails to find the `rsync` function, otherwise. I found this info on [this](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Pipelines-deploy-with-rsync-in-php-image/qaq-p/837529#M43600) post on Atlassian Community.

Answer (score 1):

If all you wan't to do is to copy the files from the pipeline to the production server, you should you the [rsync-deploy](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/rsync-deploy) pipe, instead of the ssh-run. Your pipe configuration is gonna look pretty much like the following:

```
script:
  - pipe: atlassian/rsync-deploy:0.3.2
    variables:
      USER: $PRODUCTION_USER
      SERVER: $PRODUCTION_USER
      REMOTE_PATH: 'home/$PRODUCTION_USER'
      LOCAL_PATH: 'build'
      SSH_PORT: '22007'
```

Make sure to configure your SSH keys in pipelines properly (here is a link to our docs  for configuring SSH keys https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-ssh-keys-in-bitbucket-pipelines-847452940.html)

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for the comment. I was using `rsync-deploy` before, but it has `--delete-after` set, which is no good for us as we don't want to delete everything on the server after syncing. It's been mentioned before [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-Pipelines-questions/how-to-get-rid-of-the-delete-after-flag-rsync-deploy-0-2-0/qaq-p/1094181), but the solution to force the pipeline to fail was not suitable. You had mentioned that you would consider if `--delete-after` should be optional, and I think it really should be [1/2]

Comment: because we need to sync files to the home directory as well as the `www` directory, so `--delete-after` removes all of the extra directories and dotfiles that exist in the home directory (which would obviously break the websites we're pushing to). [2/2]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work pretty well for me

```
image: node:10.15.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: <project-path>
        script:
        - apt-get update && apt-get install -y rsync
        - ssh-keyscan -H $SSH_HOST >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
        - cd $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR
        - rsync -r -v -e ssh . $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST:/<project-path>
        - ssh $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST 'cd <project-path> && npm install'
        - ssh $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST 'pm2 restart 0'
```

> Note: Avoid using **sudo** cmd in pipeline scripts

Answer (score 0):

same issue with atlassian/default-image:3

- rsync -azv ./project_path/*
  bash: rsync: command not found

Solution:

- apt-get update && apt-get install -y rsync